# Lattice Boltzmann Method

Tags: reference-request

I have done Molecular Dynamics Simulation and now want to venture into Lattice Boltzmann Method. What would be the best reference book/lecture notes/videos for a beginner?

Comment: Have you done any research into this on your own? What books and other sources are you considering? What is your criteria for "best" (e.g. a book to use as an in-depth reference or a book to quickly learn the basics). Currently this question seems overly broad to me.

Comment: Yeah I have started with some books - one is **The Lattice Boltzmann Equation for Fluid Dynamics and Beyond by Sauro Succi** and the other is **Lattice Boltzmann Method by A A Mohamad** (Springer Verlag). The one by Succi is little long and more involved than the one by Mohamad. I want to quickly learn the principles so that I can start writing codes for **simulating droplet flows**

Comment: See [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23196/some-hints-introductions-textbooks-for-lbmlattice-boltzmann-methods-fluid-simu) on physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: @VijayMurthy You should post that comment as an answer instead, as I think it is the right one.